# Is there any android library or a way that can help me to search a facebook user by their phone number?

Tags: android

Is there any android library or a way that can help me to search a facebook user by their phone number ?
For example : If I enter phone number and click on button then I should get facebook user name If they exist on facebook.

Comment: I think this goes against facebook's privacy policies, you wouldn't be able to find users who have made their profile private

Comment: Thanks Bhargav for quick reply.. but I just wanna FB user name by searching with their phone number who have set their account details (as phone number, address and so on) for publicly access.